# Plotting Peaks function in Octave doesn't produce correct graph

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

I am trying to use octave to do a data approximation project, but I am running into some trouble testing some basic things. I'm not very experienced with octave, so I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

I'm attempting to generate a list of `x,y` points using the Halton sequence. I want to plug those `x,y` points into the `peaks` function to get the `z` peaks values for those coordinates. Next, I want to plot those `x,y,z` points to be sure that my plot resembles the peak plot, but my plot looks wrong.

Here is the code:

```
%13 for this example to compare to meshgrid
N = 13;

%creates a halton sequence for N and scales it between -3 to 3
seq = haltonseq(N, 2) * 6 – 3;

%save the x,y coordinate from the halton sequence
X = seq(:,1);
Y = seq(:,2);

%convert the x,y vector in matrixes
X = repmat(X, 1, N)';
Y = repmat(Y,1,N);

%get the z values for x,y
Z = peaks(X, Y);

%plot my x,y,z values
surf(X,Y,Z);

%plot meshgrid to compare to
[mX mY] = meshgrid(-3:0.5:3);
mZ = peaks(mX, mY);
surf(mX, mY, mZ);
```

The Halton sequence is correct, but I will include it for verification. This is after it has been scaled to be between `-3` and `3`:

```
seq =

   0.00000  -1.00000
  -1.50000   1.00000
   1.50000  -2.33333
  -2.25000  -0.33333
   0.75000   1.66667
  -0.75000  -1.66667
   2.25000   0.33333
  -2.62500   2.33333
   0.37500  -2.77778
  -1.12500  -0.77778
   1.87500   1.22222
  -1.87500  -2.11111
   1.12500  -0.11111
```

Mesh Graph:

[image: Mesh Graph]

Halton Graph `N = 13`:

[image]

Halton Graph `N = 300`:

[image]

Now, to the best of my understanding of this code, the Halton sequence plot should not look like it does, and as I increase `N`, it should resemble the `meshgrid` graph more, but it keeps its same deformed shape. I'm not sure where I am going wrong, can someone point me in the right direction?

Note: I am using this code with Octave now, but I will also be using it with Matlab later, so I tagged it as both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick look at your `X` and `Y` reveals the problem:

```
octave:33> X
X =

   0.00000  -1.50000   1.50000  -2.25000   0.75000  -0.75000   2.25000  -2.62500   0.37500  -1.12500   1.87500  -1.87500   1.12500
   0.00000  -1.50000   1.50000  -2.25000   0.75000  -0.75000   2.25000  -2.62500   0.37500  -1.12500   1.87500  -1.87500   1.12500
   0.00000  -1.50000   1.50000  -2.25000   0.75000  -0.75000   2.25000  -2.62500   0.37500  -1.12500   1.87500  -1.87500   1.12500
   0.00000  -1.50000   1.50000  -2.25000   0.75000  -0.75000   2.25000  -2.62500   0.37500  -1.12500   1.87500  -1.87500   1.12500
   0.00000  -1.50000   1.50000  -2.25000   0.75000  -0.75000   2.25000  -2.62500   0.37500  -1.12500   1.87500  -1.87500   1.12500
   0.00000  -1.50000   1.50000  -2.25000   0.75000  -0.75000   2.25000  -2.62500   0.37500  -1.12500   1.87500  -1.87500   1.12500
   0.00000  -1.50000   1.50000  -2.25000   0.75000  -0.75000   2.25000  -2.62500   0.37500  -1.12500   1.87500  -1.87500   1.12500
   0.00000  -1.50000   1.50000  -2.25000   0.75000  -0.75000   2.25000  -2.62500   0.37500  -1.12500   1.87500  -1.87500   1.12500
   0.00000  -1.50000   1.50000  -2.25000   0.75000  -0.75000   2.25000  -2.62500   0.37500  -1.12500   1.87500  -1.87500   1.12500
   0.00000  -1.50000   1.50000  -2.25000   0.75000  -0.75000   2.25000  -2.62500   0.37500  -1.12500   1.87500  -1.87500   1.12500
   0.00000  -1.50000   1.50000  -2.25000   0.75000  -0.75000   2.25000  -2.62500   0.37500  -1.12500   1.87500  -1.87500   1.12500
   0.00000  -1.50000   1.50000  -2.25000   0.75000  -0.75000   2.25000  -2.62500   0.37500  -1.12500   1.87500  -1.87500   1.12500
   0.00000  -1.50000   1.50000  -2.25000   0.75000  -0.75000   2.25000  -2.62500   0.37500  -1.12500   1.87500  -1.87500   1.12500

octave:34> Y
Y =

  -1.00000  -1.00000  -1.00000  -1.00000  -1.00000  -1.00000  -1.00000  -1.00000  -1.00000  -1.00000  -1.00000  -1.00000  -1.00000
   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000
  -2.33333  -2.33333  -2.33333  -2.33333  -2.33333  -2.33333  -2.33333  -2.33333  -2.33333  -2.33333  -2.33333  -2.33333  -2.33333
  -0.33333  -0.33333  -0.33333  -0.33333  -0.33333  -0.33333  -0.33333  -0.33333  -0.33333  -0.33333  -0.33333  -0.33333  -0.33333
   1.66667   1.66667   1.66667   1.66667   1.66667   1.66667   1.66667   1.66667   1.66667   1.66667   1.66667   1.66667   1.66667
  -1.66667  -1.66667  -1.66667  -1.66667  -1.66667  -1.66667  -1.66667  -1.66667  -1.66667  -1.66667  -1.66667  -1.66667  -1.66667
   0.33333   0.33333   0.33333   0.33333   0.33333   0.33333   0.33333   0.33333   0.33333   0.33333   0.33333   0.33333   0.33333
   2.33333   2.33333   2.33333   2.33333   2.33333   2.33333   2.33333   2.33333   2.33333   2.33333   2.33333   2.33333   2.33333
  -2.77778  -2.77778  -2.77778  -2.77778  -2.77778  -2.77778  -2.77778  -2.77778  -2.77778  -2.77778  -2.77778  -2.77778  -2.77778
  -0.77778  -0.77778  -0.77778  -0.77778  -0.77778  -0.77778  -0.77778  -0.77778  -0.77778  -0.77778  -0.77778  -0.77778  -0.77778
   1.22222   1.22222   1.22222   1.22222   1.22222   1.22222   1.22222   1.22222   1.22222   1.22222   1.22222   1.22222   1.22222
  -2.11111  -2.11111  -2.11111  -2.11111  -2.11111  -2.11111  -2.11111  -2.11111  -2.11111  -2.11111  -2.11111  -2.11111  -2.11111
  -0.11111  -0.11111  -0.11111  -0.11111  -0.11111  -0.11111  -0.11111  -0.11111  -0.11111  -0.11111  -0.11111  -0.11111  -0.11111
```

As you can see, they are not sorted properly.
When plotting, order (usually) matters; see below for an explanation.
Adding the following two lines after the `repmat` fixes it:

```
X = sort(X,2);
Y = sort(Y,1);
```

Here's the result:

[image]

---

**Explanation**

The problem is that, when plotting graphs where lines have to be drawn between points, ordering matters.
To illustrate, consider this small example:

```
x1 = [1 2 3 4];
x2 = [3 1 4 2];
plot(x1,x1.^2);
plot(x2,x2.^2);
```

These two will plot the exact same points, but in a different order.
The lines joining them will hence look different:

Plot for `x1`:

[image]

Plot for `x2`:

[image]

Comment: I didn't realize the surface plot required sorted order. Thanks for the explanation.